# Apache mod_proxy_balancer dynamically stop forwarding requests to time-outing member

Tags: apache2, load-balancing, mod-proxy

Apache mod_proxy_balancer

I'm trying to gonfigure apache mod_proxy_balancer to act as HTTP VIP and represent 2 IIS servers behind it.

This how the VIP configured:

```
<Proxy balancer://appcluster>
        BalancerMember http://IP-IIS1:80 route=iis1 max=160 timeout=60
        BalancerMember http://IP-IIS2:80 route=iis2 max=160 timeout=60
        ProxySet stickysession=SERVERID
        Order Allow,Deny
        Allow from all
        Deny from XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX
        Deny from XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX
</Proxy>
```

Sometimes I have scheduled task that executed on one of the IIS servers. It could be any one of them. Since I can't bind it to one of the servers it can start on any IIS, and here comes the problem:

When the task been executed it causes to one of the servers to be very slow on incoming requests serving so it takes it very long time to serve the requests that forwarded to it by the Apache, more that the timeout configured in Apache 60 sec.

Is there any way to make mod_proxy_balancer to recognize such condition and stop forwarding the requests to the slow server, e.g dynamicaly take it out from the balancing pool?

Comment: I found this but I'm not sure it will answer my needs: `<Proxy balancer://appcluster timeout=10 maxattempts=2 lbmethod=byrequests>`

Answer (score 0):

> This module requires the service of mod_status. Balancer manager
>   enables dynamic update of balancer members. You can use balancer
>   manager to change the balance factor or a particular member, or put it
>   in the off line mode.
>
> Thus, in order to get the ability of load balancer management,
>   mod_status and mod_proxy_balancer have to be present in the server.
>
> To enable load balancer management for browsers from the example.com
>   domain add this code to your httpd.conf configuration file
>
> SetHandler balancer-manager
>
> Order Deny,Allow Deny from all Allow from .example.com
>
> You can now access load balancer manager by using a Web browser to
>   access the page http://your.server.name/balancer-manager

-> http://ceviri.belgeler.gen.tr/apache/htdocs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy_balancer.html

Comment: How visibility of the threads, workers etc solves the problem I've described above? I need something that automatically will stop forwarding request to the slow responsive server.